# Trouble deploying Django application to AWS via Jenkins and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-extras

I have a Django application hosted on an EC2 instance that I deploy manually via `eb deploy`. This is my production instance, and works fine. The Ec2 instance is an Amazon **Linux 2 Platform**.

I'm standing up a dev server using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3cAH5ZFzWs). I wanted to include a Jenkins pipeline, so I am. I was able to deploy a barebones EB application to an **Amazon Linux 2023** platform, but now I'm trying to deploy my own application. I think the change from `Amazon Linux 2` to `Amazon Linux 2023` might be a part of the issue. I'm pretty new to dev ops/infra and I'm trying my best to figure it out.

The tutorial I'm following (as well as several other sources) made it seem that I need to use an Ubuntu EC2 instance. So **Ubuntu** as the **OS** w/ **Amazon Linux 2023** as the **platform** (please correct me if my terminology is incorrect)

My Jenkins builds are pushing to AWS for deployment, but they are failing. The intial errors complain about `yum` and `amazon-linux-extras`. Through some reaserch, I beleve that the `amazon-linux-extras` package is not requred on Amazon Linux 2023, but maybe that's not correct.

Regardless, when I push with the 01_packages.config **empty**, rather than what my production uses:

```
commands:
    01_postgres_activate:
        command: sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql10
    02_postgres_install:
        command: sudo yum install -y postgresql-devel
```

as well as clear out my linux.config (probably needs to be adjusted for Ubuntu somehow, but making it empty does not work either):

```
commands:
  libcurl-devel:
    command: sudo yum install -y libcurl-devel
    ignoreErrors: true
  openssl-devel:
    command: sudo yum install -y openssl-devel
    ignoreErrors: true
```

my config.yml file looks like:

```
branch-defaults:
  main:
    environment: RVM-dev
    group_suffix: null
environment-defaults:
  Rvm-dev-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: RVM-dev
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: rvm_keypair
  default_platform: Python 3.11
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

The deployment fails. When I download the full logs, I don't see anything pertaining to deployment errors.

Any suggestions on what is incorrect, or how I can debug further?

Comment: Amazon Linux has RPM-based packaging manager, they changed from yum to dnf [in their own words](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/package-management.html), while Ubuntu until recently has DEB-based packaging.

In other words, you have to figure out why Ubuntu is mentioned at all. No, I'm not interested in watching videos, texts please.

Comment: "This is because they are part of image types that currently support the code deploy agent package"

Comment: Most likely there are error messages left on you log files.  Did you look at cfn-init.log file?  If you didn't get the file on full log SSH into your instance and check for the file in /var/log/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm sure that this would work with Ubuntu if I reconfigured my app to work that way (deps and such). However, here is how I got it all working by switching to amazon linux 2:

[Jenkins unable to connect to github private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76536785/jenkins-unable-to-connect-to-github-private-repo)