# Jenkins unable to connect to github private repo

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, git, jenkins, private-repository

I'm running Jenkins on an AWS Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance.

I have setup the instance and have jenkins running as well. I'm currently trying to add the job to deploy my private repo (Django web app) to the EC2 instance.

I have used `ssh-keygen` and placed the public key in my github SSH keys and the private key in my credentials within Jenkins.

I have been researching and almost every [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931977/add-github-private-repo-to-jenkins)  does exactly what I've been doing.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I know that github changed some of their login capabilities in the last few years, so i'm not sure if these posts are outdated.

This is the error I'm getting

[image]

You can see my credentials config below:

[image]

And my github ssh key here:

[image]

I have verified that I am able to authenticate from my EC2 instance via `ssh -T git@github.com` (Jenkins still not authenticating):

[image]

I have also tried using a username/password authorization (private key as password), but that gives the exact same error:

[image]

Comment: Try using https instead of ssh and change your credentials to username/password with the password being a GitHub personal access token. If that works then you can be sure that this is due to some configuration error with ssh, and not with Jenkins/Github acess.

Comment: That didn't work either, still getting the same error. It's strange b/c it seems most people get more of an error than "Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git ls-remote -h https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git HEAD". I've seen others getting an explanation of the why it failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the issue was two fold:

1. I'm aware that github authentication did change in the past few months/years. So, I did change my authentication to username/password.

I used my github username and a generated token from github as my password (settings -> developer settings -> personal access tokens -> classic -> generate new token)

2. I didn't have git installed on my amazon linux 2 machine AND the default path to git was for a windows machine. I solved by:

- ssh-ing to my ec2 instance (hosting Jenkins) and installed git via `sudo yum install git`
- Navigating to my jenkins instance and changing the path (path of install can be located w/ command `which git` (/usr/bin/git). Manage Jenkins -> Tools -> git installations -> (see screenshot below

[image])

And now we're good to go!

[image]